# matplotlib plot rotation 90 degree is not happening

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, svg

I am finding the edges of the images using matplotlib.I have done almost.And i want to rotate the image as 90 degree in plot.But it is not working for me.I have tried many things.Below is my code what i have tried.

```
from scipy import misc
from skimage import color,measure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.draw import ellipse
from skimage.measure import find_contours, approximate_polygon, subdivide_polygon
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

filename = r"images/5601.jpg"
fimg = misc.imread(filename)
gimg = color.colorconv.rgb2grey(fimg)
contours = measure.find_contours(gimg, 0.8)
for n, contour in enumerate(contours):
    plt.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0], linewidth=2)

contour = contours[0]
new_s = contour.copy()
appr_s = approximate_polygon(new_s, tolerance=0.8)
fig, ax2 = plt.subplots(ncols=1, figsize=(7, 5))
ax2.plot(contour[:, 0], contour[:, 1])

#these are all what i have tried
#plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
# for tick in ax2.get_xticklabels():
    # tick.set_rotation(45)
#plt.setp(ax2.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=70 )
#ax2.tick_params(axis='both', rotation=45)
#fig.autofmt_xdate(bottom=0.5, rotation=90, ha='right')
#plt.hist(ax2, bins=10, orientation='horizontal')


plt.axis('off')
plt.tick_params(axis='both' , left='off', top='off', right='off', bottom='off', labelleft='off', labeltop='off', labelright='off', labelbottom='off')
plt.savefig("test.svg", format="svg")
```

The output is:

[image]

Expected output is:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a lot of options here. It is important to note that rotating the ticks will not help here. Instead, use either of the following.

- **Flip the axes** using `invert_yaxis()`. This would not rotate the image, but flip the axes the image is shown in vertically.

  ```
  ax2.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0])
  ax2.invert_yaxis()
  ```
- **Flip the image** using `numpy.flipud`. This would not rotate the image, but flip it vertically before processing it further.

  ```
  fimg = plt.imread(filename)
  fimg = np.flipud(fimg)
  # ...
  ax2.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0])
  ```
- **Rotate the image** using `numpy.rot90`. In fact you would need to rotate it by 180 degrees (`k=2`).

  ```
  fimg = plt.imread(filename)
  fimg = np.rot90(fimg,k=2)
  # ...
  ax2.plot(contour[:, 1], contour[:, 0])
  ```
- **Rotate the output curve**

  ```
  mat = lambda angle: np.array([[ np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)],
                                [-np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])
  rotcontour = np.dot(contour, mat(np.deg2rad(180)))
  ax2.plot(rotcontour[:, 1], rotcontour[:, 0])
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response..i ll check this now @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: I have checked all the function..It works well.This is what i need.Thanks again.

Comment: And i  have one doubt is there any option to get the same width and height of uploaded image?output shows different width and height

Comment: You need to set the aspect of the axes, `ax.set_aspect()` and the axes limits according to the input. This would be different for each of the solutions presented here.

Comment: ok i ll check that..but image not rotating properly for all image..and i need to reverse the curve again from your solution

Comment: For example  see this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWcMB.png)..how the B is displaying..

Comment: Which of the solutions are you talking about?

Comment: I am using the last one..what is the problem know whatever coming left side that has to go right side.. whatever shows right side has to come left side...

Comment: I cannot reprodruce this. It is working as expected for me.

Comment: Please need some time i ll check again and come back

Comment: i have done like this: `mat = lambda angle: np.array([[ np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)], [-np.sin(angle), np.cos(angle)]])
    rotcontour = np.dot(contour, mat(np.deg2rad(0)))
    ax2.plot(rotcontour[:, 1], rotcontour[:, 0])
    ax2.invert_yaxis()`..This works..Thanks again

Comment: But what is the root cause of image getting flipped by 90 degrees??