# import _tkinter in Google CloudPlatforms

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-cloud-platform

In my python application i am using the matplotlib.when i start running it throws me an error:

> ImportError: No named '_tkinter', please install the python3-tk package

Then i have installed `sudo apt-get install python-tk`.It got works in localhost.But same app i am deploying into the google cloudPlatforms.But i am getting this error:

> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk ImportError: libBLT.2.5.so.8.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How to install python-tk to Google cloudPlatforms.After deactivate the vitualenv also i have installed.It shows already the newest version.I have tried many things but it doesn't seems to work.The App throws 502 Bad Gateway.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't run tkinter on headless servers. Tkinter is designed to work with a display.

Comment: how to overcome this issue?Is there any other way?

Comment: That depends on what your issue really is. Do you need to use some feature of tkinter? Or, are you trying to use matplotlib and it is misconfigured to use tkinter instead of something else?

Comment: I want to use matplotlib only..i am trying the Iguananaut's answer..

Comment: Actually the answer doesn't help.i have commented the code link and error also in Iguananaut's answer..Please have a look @Bryan Oakley

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
matplotlib.use('agg')
```

right after importing matplotlib, to render matplotlib graphics in a headless environment.  You can also set this as the default in your `matplotlibrc` file, or via the `MPLBACKEND` environment variable.

See the matplotlib docs for more details: https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend  See also the page on [using matplotlib in a web application](https://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#howto-webapp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer with the link..I ll try this now.

Comment: I am getting the same error..i have tried this..See my [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUdja.png)

Comment: This is my [code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47035631/4356233)..i have added `matplotlib.use('agg')` this also did `import matplotlib`..

Comment: No it didn't work.. In second comment I linked the error image..I have commanded all the code other than 'from, import' and I checked.still it keeps the error.. while importing itself it throws the error

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, check also defaults set via `matplotlibrc`, the `MPLBACKEND` environment variable, or the like.  If your default backend is `tkinter` then it might try to import `tkinter` before you get a chance in the code to change the backend (although I think this is unusual...).

Comment: Ok I ll check that

Comment: I have added before import all other modules..It works like a charm..Thank you